# Directly save files to Folder using Jquery/javascript(Without controller)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i save a file using jquery  and html(without any controller).

here is the code:

```
 $("#tab3_fileaccdoc", r).change(function (e) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    //var totalFiles = document.getElementById(e.id).files.length;
                    var file = document.getElementById(e.id).files[0];
                    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/fundprovider/newfundUpload_investmentlogo',
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (files, data, xhr) {
                            $("#tab3edit_fileaccdoc").val(files);
                            $("#hdnAccountDocument").val(files);
                        },
                        error: function (error) {

                        }
                    });
                })
```

but with out using controller or anything .. i want to save files directly in a folder using javscript or jquery.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is impossible since saving file to the server's hard drive requires... e-e-m... an application server. Probably you can use some ready-to-use app server for such purposes.

From your example I see that you are actually trying to send file to `/fundprovider/newfundUpload_investmentlogo` endpoint - which at the end can be a controller. You are clearly messed up with understanding of what a server is. So I suggest you to investigate client-server architecture first.

Comment: Sir I have some html form and I am working on angularjs..So is there any way in html form so that I can save file in a folder...I think there may be any method or functionality in JavaScript or jquery file upload with directly to the folders..So if any thing such like just suggest me.

Comment: What do you mean by "save file in a folder"? Do you want to save file via browser ("Save as" window) on end-user computer? Or you want to save user's file on the server?

Comment: Check answers on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file